# Facebook login with js sdk - demand email scope as requested

Tags: facebook-login

In the last few days I've started to work with the Facebook JS SDK. Now I want to add a Facebook login to my site.

When I open the login dialog with FB.login, I added the 'scope' parameter with the relevant data that I need... email is one of them.

In the dialog the user can edit and change the data he accepts to give.

So, my question is: how can I disable/remove the option of changing the data he accepts?
I want to force the user to give me his email... so I will check that his email exists OR not exists yet and process.

The best example to see that is possible is to use 'stackoverflow' login via Facebook.
In this case the dialog just tells me that I'm gonna give the public profile and my email, and I don't have the option to change it.

I search in the internet/facebook docs/stackoverflow and I didn't find any answer for this.

The code im using is:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}, {
  scope: 'public_profile,email', 
  return_scopes: true
});
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't force user to give your email at first time.
What you should do is to try login user, then check his granted scopes and if there is no email you should send rerequest for email (by adding "auth_type: 'rerequest'" to FB.login options.
Everything is described in FB docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.3